# Laravel package for visual page editor

Tags: javascript, php, html-editor, live-preview

I have a PHP website with Laravel 4 framework.

I would like to find a visual page editor tool to integrate at front-end website that admin can edit content both of text and image like the [Visual Composer plugin for WordPress](http://vc.wpbakery.com) or Mailchimp UI when compose a new e-mail.

Comment: No there is no Package like that currently for Laravel but we are currently building one at [Minisoft Group](http://www.minisoftgroup.com/) and will soon be through with it and once we are done with it, we will Notify you.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this package in the past, it's a fork of PHPageBuilder which itself is based on GrapesJS.

https://github.com/HansSchouten/Laravel-Pagebuilder